# Constant fields in Facebook graph api 'me' edge?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems clear that the 'id' field of the graph API for the 'me' edge is unique per user/app, immutable and is guaranteed not to change over the life of the app. Based upon the documentation the 'third_party_id' field appears to be the same.

We'd like to understand how likely these fields are to change over time (if at all) as we develop code around them. Can we rely upon these fields remaining constant per user/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user

Both are unique and will stay the same. I´ve never used the `third_party_id`, but i guess it´s for giving away an App Scoped ID to a third party to keep the App Scoped User ID hidden from it.

Comment: Thanks @luschn - yes I did see that... I guess I was looking for something definitive to indicate it'll always remain the same.

Comment: oh, it will remain the same, but i suggest just using the app scoped id.